# Python parse inline css

Tags: python, css, parsing, svg

I'm using Python to get the style information from an SVG file, but don't know how to parse the information.

Here is an example:

```
fill:#00ff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none
```

I want to get the `stroke` and `stroke-width` from that string. How can I do that

Comment: Have you tried anything out yet?  [Regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) might be something to look into.

Comment: Please explain the issues with the question before down-voting so I can improve it.

Comment: @Numeri regex can't parse that, you actually need a css parser, there will be `:` and `;` within property values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary

```
attr_string ="fill:#00ff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"

attr_dict = {pair.split(":")[0]:pair.split(":")[1] for pair in attr_string.split(";")}
```

Comment: Thank you. Simple, but effective!

Comment: @canyon289 It doesn't cover complex styles as `background:white url('data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/')`  Semicolon can be fixed in this way `pair.split(":", 1)` but about `";"` I am not sure